# Is there a way to detect the number of players on a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Pizzaspleef ( a game made by SethBling), you are allowed to start a game only if there are 2 or more players on the server.

How do I detect how many players are on the server in a similar way?

Comment: ...what? This makes no sense, please elaborate on your question.

Comment: I made a drastic edit based on my understanding of your question. Can you confirm that this is in fact what you want to know?

Comment: I am going to assume this is based on using commands and command blocks.

Comment: Thats generally how it is when it has the 'minecraft-commands' tag, @Shadow Z

Answer (score 3):

If you hook a comparator to a command block with the `testfor` command, the output signal strength is equal to the amount of people detected (maximum 15). For example

```
/testfor @a[x=0,y=64,z=0,r=10]
```

Puts out a signal strength equal to the amount of players in a 10 block radius around 0, 64, 0. If you hook this command onto a fast clock, detecting at least two players is as easy as having two pieces of redstone dust after the comparator. From there, you can invert the signal using a torch, then use a repeater pointing sideways into another repeater that is part of the activation circuit. That way, the output of the second repeater can not change unless you have at least two players online.